# Prove that $4x-x^4 \leq 3, x \in \Bbb R$

Tags: inequality

How can I tackle the following inequality :

> Prove that $4x-x^4 \leq 3$, where $x$  is any real number.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you accepted an elegant answer that doesn't require calculus, but if you know a little calculus, it is easy:  let $f(x) = 4x -x^4$.  $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $|x| \to \infty$, so $f$ achieves a maximum value at some $x_0$.  $f'(x_0) = 0$.  $f'(x) = 4 - 4x^3$ so $x_0 = 1$.  $f(1) = 3$ is the maximum value of $f$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We see that ,  $x^4-4x+3=x^4-2x^2+1+2x^2-4x+2=(x^2-1)^2+2(x-1)^2 \geq 0$ and so $-(x^4-4x+3)\leq 0 \implies  -x^4+4x-3 \leq 0$ and 
hence   $4x-x^4 \leq 3$

Answer (score 15):

You could also apply $\mathrm{AM}-\mathrm{GM}$

$$\frac{x^{4}+1+1+1}{4} \geq \sqrt[4]{x^{4} 1\cdot 1\cdot  1}   =|x|$$

Comment: Wow! what a nice a nice approach. thanks a lot @clark. +1 from me.

Comment: @user53386 glad I could help:)

Answer (score 7):

Hint:
$4x-x^4-3=-(x-1)^2((x+1)^2+2)\le0$

Answer (score 2):

For your question, consider rearranging the inequality to $$\begin{align*}4x-x^4 &\leq 3\\4x-x^4-3 &\leq 0 \end{align*}$$
Now let's prove it. For all real $x$, consider the stationary value of the function

> *(let's say I didn't read the question and do not know if the stationary value is a minimum or maximum)*

$$f(x)=4x-x^4-3$$ First order condition:$$\begin{align*}f'(x)=4-4x^3&=0\\4x^3&=4\\x^3&=1\\x&=1\end{align*}$$
Second order condition:$$\begin{align*}f''(x)=-12x^2&=-12\end{align*}$$
and so we conclude the maximum value of $f$ is at $x=1$. $f(1)=4-1-3=0$. We say that $f$ can never go beyond $0$, or $f(x)\leq0$ for all real $x$. It agrees with the initial inequality and hence it is true.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bryansis2010  . Nice approach. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by some calculus. It is clear for $x \leq 0$. $4x - x^4$ is increasing until $x = 1$, where we have $4x - x^4 = 3$ on the dot, so we have it for $x \in [0,1]$. Then it decreases afterwards, so we have it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = 4x-x^4-3$. Note that $y$ has just 1 extrema: $\sqrt[3]{(\frac 4 3)}$. $y$ is not positive at this point, so as isn't at $\infty$ and$-\infty$, therefore it isn't positive at $(-\infty;~\infty)$.